# How can I get the error message that the mouse is hovering over?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging

I'm trying to write an editor related to debugging. I believe there isn't any function in Unity that allows me to retrieve debug messages. Is it possible to access the error message I select in the Debug window?

[image]

I tried the Application.logMessageReceived function, but it doesn't work in the editor.

Comment: I dont believe it works that way. I believe you have to trap the debug messages as they are made, then you can do something with them if you control the window etc.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ILogger.html

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve this using reflection. I'll provide you with an example.

```cs
        // Get the Assembly of Unity
        var assembly = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly;

        // Get the type UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow
        var consoleWindowType = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow");

        // Retrieve the ms_ConsoleWindow field
        var ms_ConsoleWindowField = consoleWindowType.GetField("ms_ConsoleWindow", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Get the value of ms_ConsoleWindow to obtain the ConsoleWindow object
        var consoleWindow = (EditorWindow)ms_ConsoleWindowField.GetValue(null);

        // Retrieve the m_SelectedLogEntry field
        var m_SelectedLogEntryField = consoleWindowType.GetField("m_ActiveText", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Get the value of m_SelectedLogEntry from the ConsoleWindow object
        var selectedLogEntry = m_SelectedLogEntryField.GetValue(consoleWindow);

        // Extract the log message from selectedLogEntry
        var selectedLog = selectedLogEntry?.ToString();
```

[Github Gist example link](https://gist.github.com/srktnc/ffedadf23a796815d76ccd37437f1be9)

Comment: This is incredible. It worked perfectly for me. Thank you, my friend.